# Сбор информации о вступивших пользователях группу ВК

Tags: алгоритм, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Какое api или какой алгоритм нужно использовать, что бы собирать данные о вступивших пользователях в определенную группу ВК. (В этой группе я не являюсь администратором). Нужно узнать ID вступивших в группу с определённого момента (Раз в день).